# AWS API Gateway - Not Accepting Multipart form data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a API endpoint built in FastAPI (python) which takes multipart form data and look like this.

```
@partner_data_router.post("/partner/edit")
async def edit_partner(request: Request,
                       logo: UploadFile = File(None),
                       banner: UploadFile = File(None),
                       id_: str = Form(None),
                       title: str = Form(None),
                       description: str = Form(None),
                       subtitle: str = Form(None),
                       wallet: str = Form(None),
                       links: list = Form([]),
                       type_: str = Form(None),
                       is_available: str = Form(None)
                       ):
    try:
        # Debug logging
        content_type = request.headers.get('content-type')
        logger.debug(f"Request content-type: {content_type}")

        token = request.headers.get('x-access-token')
        company = verify_sass_token(token)
        partner = {
            "id": id_,
            "title": title,
            "subtitle": subtitle,
            "description": description,
            "wallet": wallet,
            "type": type_
        }
        path = "/" + company.company_id + "/partners/"
        # If an image was not provided, the corresponding variable will be None
        if logo:
            print(f"A main image was uploaded with filename: {logo.filename}")
            name = logo.filename
            path = path + "logo"
            path_ = await image_kit_funcs.upload_to_imagekit(logo, name, path, False)
            partner['logo'] = path_

        if banner:
            print(f"A main image was uploaded with filename: {banner.filename}")
            name = banner.filename
            path = path + "banner"
            path_ = await image_kit_funcs.upload_to_imagekit(banner, name, path, False)
            partner['banner'] = path_

        # Process links
        links_ = []
        for l in links:
            try:
                lj = json.loads(l)
                links_.extend(lj)
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                logger.error(f"JSON decode error in links: {e}")
                raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid format in links")

        if links_:
            partner['links'] = links_

        # Process availability
        partner["is_available"] = is_available.lower() == "true"

        r = partner_data_db.edit_partner(company.company_id, partner)
        return JSONResponse("edited", 200)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in edit_partner: {e}", exc_info=True)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")
```

It works fine when called directly, however when I call it via AWS API Gateway, I get an error in the logs.

```
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]: [2024-01-24 09:57:58 +0000] [10297] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/starlette.py", line 364, in _sentry_patched_asgi_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     return await middleware(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/asgi.py", line 146, in _run_asgi3
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     return await self._run_app(scope, receive, send, asgi_version=3)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/asgi.py", line 241, in _run_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     raise exc from None
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/asgi.py", line 234, in _run_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     return await self.app(
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/starlette.py", line 157, in _create_span_call
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     return await old_call(app, scope, new_receive, new_send, **kwargs)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     raise exc
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 83, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/starlette.py", line 256, in _sentry_exceptionmiddleware_call
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await old_call(self, scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/starlette.py", line 157, in _create_span_call
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     return await old_call(app, scope, new_receive, new_send, **kwargs)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     raise exc
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await app(scope, receive, sender)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 762, in __call__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 782, in app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     raise exc
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     await app(scope, receive, sender)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     response = await func(request)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 285, in app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     raise e
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 275, in app
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 626, in solve_dependencies
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     ) = await request_body_to_args(  # body_params checked above
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 751, in request_body_to_args
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 678, in __aexit__
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  |     raise BaseExceptionGroup(
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  | ExceptionGroup: unhandled errors in a TaskGroup (1 sub-exception)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:    | Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:    |   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 753, in request_body_to_args
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:    |     tg.start_soon(process_fn, sub_value.read)
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:    | AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
Jan 24 09:57:58 ip-172-31-16-152 web[10297]:    +------------------------------------
```

If I disable the the image files from the endpoint it works again, so I believe it is something to do with the way the multipart file uploads are passed through but can't pinpoint the issue in the API Gateway.